# show content on two columns with a limited height

Tags: html, css

I am having hard time to design a content which is dynamic and will have many paragraphs. From those content, i want the text to be shown in two columns. If the content reaches to the specified height then remaining content should be shown on another column.

here is the screenshot to show how exactly i want

[image]

I will get the content in following form

```
<div class="description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</div>
```

I tried using max-height but it did not work. I tried css as

```
.description {
  display: flex;
}

.description p:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
}

.description p:nth-child(2) {
  flex:1;
}
```

but if you see in the screenshot, there is two paragraph on the left. There might be three small paragraph as well in the left before it reach to limited height.

How can i have similar designs based on above html?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for soemthing like this, Not sure if what you are looking for is possible. Also checkout flex examples https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-top;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > p {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The align-content Property</h1>

<p>The "align-content: flex-end;" displays the flex lines at the end of the container:</p>

<div class="flex-container">
<p>The "align-content: space-around;" displays the flex lines with space before, between, and after them:</p>

<div class="flex-container">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `column-fill` property:

[Column-Fill](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-fill.asp)

> This will help you to use the column as you desire. when the content increases then the data will be flowed to next column without doing any extra code.

```css
p {
  column-count: 2; /* number of columns you need*/
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%;
}

.description {
  column-fill: auto; /* you either can choose balance/auto as options */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
      the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
      the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
      ever since the 1500s.
    </p>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
      the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
      the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
      ever since the 1500s.
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we not make the content flow to right side only if the content reaches to the height of around 300px?

Comment: you mean to have 3rd column? or in 2nd column itsef? if it is 2nd column you should specify overflow for either `x` or `y`. look at this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/b2txyv4r/9/

Comment: it should be of only 2 column. For first (left) it should have content up to 300 px height and remaining content should be on second column(right) up to 300px height.

Comment: ok, so what should happen when the content exceeds 2 columns of 300px? it should go somewhere right? so what is it you need? at present if you observe the snippet the first columns will take the content upto 300px then more content will be moved to 2nd column and if exceeds then it again moves to next column, so you have to fit-n the content somewhere. If you think there won't be no more content then snippet works for your case.

Comment: this is what i wanted to move the content to another column when it exceeds 300px. But in your example if i put less content on first p tag and then create another p tag with moderate content then it does work as expected. you can see an example here https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/b2txyv4r/9/.  The first two paragraph should be on first column because it has not huge content which exceeds stated height.

Comment: oh ok got it, you just remove the column-fill option: check this https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/b2txyv4r/12/ this has one column only then it moves to next column only if the content increases. let me know.

Comment: it seems like more than on paragraph cannot have in first column even if their content are less than stated height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211798/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-serenity).